# Как выбрать максимальные значения по группам?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужно выбрать максимальные "value" по каждой группе "name".

Имеется таблица:

```
id      name    value  
1402    н-055   0  
1466    н-055   1  
1503    н-055   2  
1410    н-066   0  
1420    н-066   1  
1510    н-070   0  
1620    н-070   1 
2000    н-001   0
```

Выборкой получить результат:

```
id      name    value  
1503    н-055   2  
1420    н-066   1 
1620    н-070   1
2000    н-001   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант без подзапроса, используя `TOP 1 WITH TIES` и `RANK`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES id, name, value FROM t
ORDER BY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY value DESC)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from T join
(select name, max(value) value from T group by name) TT
on T.name=TT.name and T.value=TT.value
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM таблица ORDER BY value DESC
```

Comment: Судя по примеру, ТС хочет получить максимальные значения `value` из каждой группы `name`, а не все вместе.